# Can a wildcard be used to call variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, wildcard, string-matching

I have a *ton* of variables to work with here, with information going back and forth between a form in HTML. The variables need to be global so that they can work across a variety of functions. So here's one sample of the list:

```
var charDex = 0;
var charEnd = 0;
var charPer = 0;
var charStr = 0;
var charCon = 0;
var charInt = 0;
var charRat = 0;
var charRes = 0;
var charDip = 0;
var charGui = 0;
var charItd = 0;
var charLea = 0;
```

They start out at zero, data is entered into the form, a button sends the data into a JS function that stores the data, and then sends various information based on said stored data back to the form.

Now, I know I'm able to save some repetition by using functions within functions, which I've done so far. But still, there's a lot going on here. What I want to know is if there's a way to use wildcards and/or string matching to automatically match up data from form input to JS variables? The end result would be something to the effect of:

```
function updateCharacter(form){
    char* = form.c*.value;
    racial* = form.r*.value;
    mod* = form.m*.value;
    total* = char* + racial* + mod*;
    form.t*.value = total*;
}
```

In my case, charDex and form.cDex.value (etcetera) have the same suffix, so I figure there's *something* I can do, I'm just not sure what I'm missing.I thought about using a for loop with an array, but I'm not exactly certain how I could make that work.

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to achieve. What is expected result of `*` within `updateCharacter`?

Comment: There is no wild card operator for vars in JavaScript. `*` would be multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No worries!

Just use an object instead.

**edit:** removing the 'char' variable name previously used, as it's a [reserved word](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm).

```
var chars = {
    Dex: "some text",
    End: 0,
    Per: 2,
    Str: 345,
    Con: "blah blah",
    Int: 0,
    Rat: 0,
    Res: 0,
    Dip: 0,
    Gui: 0,
    Itd: 0,
    Lea: 0
}
```

You can access the values of each of these using either of the following options:

- `chars['Dex']`
- `chars.Dex`

either of these will give you "some text".

---

To iterate over the properties, try this:

```
for (prop in chars) {
    console.log( prop ); // this will log the name of the property
    console.log( chars[prop] ); // this will log the value
}
```

Comment: That already looks immensely helpful. I'll do some more digging on objects and see what tools that will give me.

Comment: @Salakavala - Oh gosh, I should've caught myself on this and warned you about it... Don't use the variable name "char" as it's a reserved keyword in JavaScript! [See a full list here!](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm) I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Salakavala - Also, no problem! You can mark my answer as accepted if it answered your question :)

Comment: I'm thinking that if I can turn the form contents into an array, and run it in parallel with the objects' properties in a for loop, then that will have the desired effect. We'll see, but either way, this is a great point in the right direction. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you need to use an array, that is also possible. Would you like me to edit my answer with that as well?

Comment: Naw, I'm good. I have a direction, and that's all I needed to get the gears turning again. Thanks, though.